# How do I shove a slice into an array?

Tags: rust

```
let mut foo: [u8; 6] = &[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let mut bar: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3]
```

I want the desired result:

```
&[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

The obvious way:

```
let foo: [u8; 6] = [bar, vec![0; 6 - bar.len()].as_slice()].concat().try_into()...
```

1. It causes a lot of overhead.
2. It's not practical

Perhaps there are some other ways?

Comment: There is an appropriate method that does this, so it's of course the best solution. But if there wasn't, I'd say a loop is definitively preferable to what you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo: [u8; 6] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let mut bar: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];
    
    println!("before: {:?}", foo); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    foo[..bar.len()].copy_from_slice(bar);
    
    println!("after: {:?}", foo); // [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```rust
fn main() {

  let mut foo: [u8; 6] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  let mut bar: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];

  foo[..3].clone_from_slice(bar);

  println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```